# OAuth 2.0 Playground - Timeout Limit?

Tags: google-apps-script, timeout, http-status-code-500, oauth2-playground

I'm using the OAuth 2.0 Playground to execute a Google App Script function.  Using:

```
https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/MSnRgD0GQVGwCP-h1YWmtpwV62A3zXXXX:run
```

The function is very simple, it just pauses for a set amount of time and then returns true.

```
function funSleep(intSeconds) {
    Utilities.sleep(intSeconds * 1000);
    return true;
}
```

If I run the function for < 55 seconds it returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 133
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Tue, 20 Mar 2018 15:11:29 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,35"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "done": true, 
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse", 
    "result": true
  }
}
```

If I run the function for > 60 seconds it returns:

Something bad happened: 500 HTTP error. Message: 
  500 Server Error

## Error: Server Error

### The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.

---

***Questions:***

Does the OAuth 2.0 Playground have a 1 minute timeout on the REST requests?  I can't find this documented anywhere and I can't see if it's possible to increase it.

I've also experimented with Postman and successfully called this function with a wait up to 4 minutes.  The [Google documentation states the limit is 6 minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), but I've been unable to achieve this result.  Has anyone managed a REST call through the Google App Script API of this length?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It makes sense to me that the website API demos don't support full usage of the hosted APIs. I'll try setting up something in the Python API client later to use the Script API and call a long-running function.