# Google Apps Script API - 4 minute Timeout?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, timeout, google-apps-script-api

The Google documentation states that ["Google App Scripts have a 6 minute runtime limit"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

I've confirmed this limit by running a sleep function which waits for 355 seconds and then returns a value in a browser.

*However*, running the same function for 355 seconds using a Google App Script API call **doesn't result in a value being returned**.  The Stackdriver logs confirm the function continues to its completion and *attempts* to return a value but this **doesn't make it back through the API**.  On the client side this causes the calling program, e.g. Postman to just timeout eventually.

The API calls **do return a value if the function completes in under 4 minutes**, e.g. the same sleep function works if it's run for 220 seconds.

**Questions:**

1) Does anyone know if the Google App Script API has been configured by Google to only utilise 66% of the timeout window available?

2) Does anyone know if the Google App Script API has any documented SLAs that would include these times?

3) Has anyone achieved a synchronous call to the Google App Script API that returned a value after 4 minutes?

Comment: Nearly identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388133/oauth-2-0-playground-timeout-limit